# Boost cpp_dec_float with precision determined at run-time

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, runtime, arbitrary-precision

Normally to create an arbitrary-length data type using Boost's `cpp_dec_float`, you use:

```cpp
typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<100> > arbFloat;
```

This is great and all, but it appears that the value for the precision (above it is `100`) needs to be constant and determined at compile-time. For example, this code does **not** compile:

```cpp
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>

int main() {
    int custom_precision = 100;
    typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<custom_precision> > arbFloat;
    return 0;
}
```

and returns the following errors:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
5:77: error: ‘custom_precision’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
  typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<custom_precision> > arbFloat;
                                                                             ^
5:93: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<custom_precision> > arbFloat;
                                                                                             ^
5:95: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<custom_precision> > arbFloat;
                                                                                               ^
5:95: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

But when `int custom_precision` is instead constant: `const int custom_precision` the program compiles fine.

**Is there a way to use Boost's `cpp_dec_float` with the precision determined at run-time, or some way to at least trick it?**

I plan to use it with command line parsing, so that I can do something like:

```
$ ./test_program --precision 500
```